# Showing DateTimeField with editable=False in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have date field which is `editable=False`.

The field is populated with `datetime.now()` at creation time.

Since admin will not show `editable=False` fields, I created a custom admin.

The custom admin uses a form with this field:

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime, required=False)
```

What I want to achieve is this:

1. users will not be able to touch this field (hence, `editable=False`)
2. Admin will be able to change the field's value but won't be forced to (this is why I have `required=False`)
3. Admin will be able to see the current value of the field.

I'm failing to achieve (3).  I create an entry, and I see that it has a valid date when I look in the database. But when I open it from admin panel, the date widget is empty.

Any ideas how to make the date widget show the current value of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `models.DateTimeField` uses `widgets.AdminSplitDateTime` by default in the Admin, you don't have to specify it explicitly.

For normal staff, use [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) to prevent the date field from being changed.

For administrator, render a different changing form to allow the modification towards the date field. In Django 1.4, it can be easily done by overriding [`ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields):

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # we don't use self.readonly_fields anymore
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ()
        return ['date']
```